# Laptop HDMI port maximum resolution external monitor supported

Tags: laptop, hdmi

I would like to know what is the maximum resolution or screen size monitor can be connected or supported for a normal laptop HDMI port.

I am planning to have my laptop screen shown on a 27 inch monitor to get ride of laptop's small screen.

Can I use external monitor native resolution and it don't burn out my laptop's graphics card?

HDMI Detail: Laptop manu has only following details about it

> This port is for a High-Definition Multimedia Interface (HDMI)
>   connector and is HDCP complaint for HD DVD, Blue-ray, and other
>   protected content playback.

Comment: Unless you tell us the exact make and model, you cannot get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which version of HDMI your laptop uses? Different HDMI versions appear to have progressively higher supported resolutions:

v1.0 = max 1920x1200
v1.3 = max 2560x1600 (single link)

http://www.hdmi.org/learningcenter/kb.aspx#32

```
burn out my laptop's graphics card?
```

You will not burn it out whatever happens. You will just see a "No signal" or a blank screen on your TV. On your computer, you will probably either see no error messages, or it will tell that the signal is out of bounds. Most likely you will not see any error messages, or a standard "Your settings have been applied, press OK if it looks good".